# Is it possible to generate functions from class?

Tags: reinforced-typings

Given a class:

```
public class
{
    public void Foo() {}
}
```

Can I generate TypeScript function

```
foo() {
}
```

Without it being enclosed in the class?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have read your question incorrectly

Code generators to rescue:

```cs
public class FunClassCodeGenerator : ClassCodeGenerator
{
    public override RtClass GenerateNode(Type element, RtClass result, TypeResolver resolver)
    {
        // obtain current namespace
        var ns = this.Context.Location.CurrentNamespace;

        // invoke base generation method
        var r = base.GenerateNode(element, result, resolver);
        foreach (var rMember in r.Members)
        {
            var m = rMember as RtFuncion;
            if (m!=null)
            {
                // remove access modifier
                m.AccessModifier = null;
                // here you can override implementation by
                // m.Body = new RtRaw("...code...");

                // append function body to current namespace
                ns.CompilationUnits.Add(m);
            }
        }

        // return null instead of result to 
        // suppress writing AST of original class 
        // to resulting file
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, in fluent configuration:

```cs
public static void Configure(ConfigurationBuilder cb)
{
    cb.ExportAsClass<SomeClass>()
        .WithPublicMethods()
        .WithCodeGenerator<FunClassCodeGenerator>()
        .DontIncludeToNamespace();
}
```

So, for `SomeClass` declared as followed:

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething() { }

    public string GetName(int arg) { return string.Empty; }
}
```

Such approach will result in your TypeScript file this code:

```js
DoSomething() : void { } 
GetName(arg: number) : string
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, return types are missing. Thanks a lot for the sample code, I'll experiment with it.